# VBA: Jump to the beginning of a for loop

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have a little problem with jumping back to the start of a for loop.

Part of the code:

```
For M = 1 To System

    Openhours = Numberofhours(M, 1)

    If Openhours = 0 Then
     M = M + 1
     Exit For
     End If
```

I can have 1-6 "Systems", more could be added. "Openhours" says how many hours is dedicated to a particular system, but the problem is that if I happen to have a system (say system number 3) where there are no hours dedicated to at the moment, then the system crashes as, for example "Openhours" is zero with quite a few other arrays.
So I'd need to tell the code that immediately if it notices that Openhours is zero that it goes back to the beginning of the loop and tests the next system.

"Exit For" did of course not work as it skipped all the other systems after it found the first system with zero hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could either check for **`Openhours`** being **NOT equal** to 0 and only execute your code in those cases, thus eliminating the need to jump to the next iteration or you could use the **`NEXT`**-keyword to jump to the next iteration of your loop.

Comment: I did somehow not think about that. =D Thanks!